# Selenium 4 and testsession

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I've been running on Selenium 4 for a few months now. Mostly, all good.

One issue keeps biting me and so far I've been unable to find a workaround.

**I'm trying to find which node a test is running on (not even test just browser session).**

Prior version of Selenium I called this API on the hub with the session id returned from driver.getSessionId()

`http://<grid>s:4444/grid/api/testsession?session=<sessionid>`

Response included:

```
     String internalKey;
     String msg;
     String proxyId;
     String session;
     boolean success;
```

Most important for me was proxyId which revealed the node name.

That API no longer works. 404

I'm surprised this is not a big topic.I've looked around for docs with no luck.

**How do you folks find the node running a browser session in a grid?**

Comment: Maybe owner or status... I think status should give you info on all nodes... check here: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/grid/advanced_features/endpoints/#grid-status

Comment: I, too, have this same issue/need.

Per the suggestion from @pcalkins I gave that a shot, but it returns everything - no easy way to determine what a particular session's info is (just returns info on all nodes).

Answer (score 0):

The Selenium documentation provides exactly one example you can take for reference:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"query":"{ session (id: \"<session-id>\") { id, capabilities, startTime, uri, nodeId, nodeUri, sessionDurationMillis, slot { id, stereotype, lastStarted } } } "}' -s <LINK_TO_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT>
```

I am able to get the required details,

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4444/graphql");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

String sessionId = "456731";

String query = "{ \"query\": \"{ session (id: \\\""+sessionId+"\\\") { id, capabilities, startTime, uri, nodeId, nodeUri, sessionDurationMillis, slot { id, stereotype, lastStarted } } } \"}";

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(query.getBytes());
os.flush();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
  (conn.getInputStream())));

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  sb.append(line);
  sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}

String result = sb.toString();

System.out.println("API Response .... \n" + result);

conn.disconnect();
```